# Discrepancy between importing same data from CSV and GPS

Tags: qgis, gps, coordinates, csv, import

I have been importing similar data by using two different methods:

1. Entering the coordinates manually in excel and save as CSV, then importing in QGIS through delimited text layer. Column A is name, column B is Easting (X) and column C is Northing (Y). WGS is set at 84 for both map and CSV layer.
2. Importing same data straight from GPS into QGIS

When I use option 1, my coordinate is corrupted and mapped 50 km from the actual location. I would like to find out why as I will create databanks using CSV.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the coordinates you are entering into the Excel file in your question?

Comment: Also, are the coordinates shifted consistently or do they all end up in a single point?

Comment: Lat/long coordinates don't have eastings/northings. If you have eastings/northings you are most likely entering projected coordinates. WGS is a datum/geographic coordinate system, 84 being the year/specific iteration of that system. I think you mean you set the CRS to WGS84 for both QGIS project and layer when you added the points. Note that GPS units *generally* default to WGS84 coordinates but *can* use other datums. Please edit your question to describe the exact steps/tools you are using in method 2, verify the CRS being used by the GPS unit, and as Dan suggested include sample coordinate.